# Integration: u-substitution and factoring out constants

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm struggling solving the following indefinite integral with u-substition.

Given:

$\int 2\sqrt[]{2x-1} dx , u=2x-1$

I begin to solve by factoring out 2, thus:

$2 \int \sqrt[]{2x-1} dx$

and rewrite with an exponent and u-substitution:

$2 \int u^{1/2} du$

which evaluates to: $\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2} + c$

"Unsubstituting" u gives:

$\frac{2}{3}(2x-1)^{3/2} + c$ (which is the correct answer on my homework sheet)

but what about the 2 we factored out in the beginning? Is not the final solution:

$2\cdot\frac{2}{3}(2x-1)^{3/2} + c$

thus:

$\frac{4}{3}(2x-1)^{3/2} + C$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have performed all the steps correctly. There is just one minor error.

In u-substitution, you set your u to be:

$$u = 2x -1$$

Therefore differentiating, we get:

$$du = 2dx,\ dx = \frac{du}{2}$$

When you substitute your $u$ into the integral you also have to make sure to substitute your $du$, or else you're taking the integral with respect with another variable.

Comment: You've given the full explanation, but @Mike's answer was also super helpful. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1):

Your homework sheet appears to be correct.  You forgot to account for the change from $dx$ to $du$.  If $u=2x-1$, then $du=2dx$.  When you substitute, you should have

$$\int2\sqrt{2x-1}dx=\int\sqrt{2x-1}(2dx)=\int\sqrt udu$$

Comment: I tend to follow "substitute for $u$ then multiply by the derivative of the first function, in this case $\frac{1}{2}$ which would cancel out the 2...but it's been factored out! I don't see how in your example $2dx$ is "gone"

Comment: Because, as said above, $du=2dx$.  One simply got swapped for the other.  The order of multiplication was simply changed to make the substitution easier.

Comment: I see, so because $du=2dx$ we substitute the 2 and $dx$ terms for $du$..Got it. Never looked at $dx$ etc as part of multiplication though....Any pointers on what to read?